# Extract a specific URL from a list of URLs using PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have a list of more than 100 Webpages where I need to find a specific URL from. For now, I have to manually scrub through each and every page to find the URL and make a note of them.  Is there a way to find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do, place your links in a file called links.txt
and replace example.com in the code with the url you want to be searched for, and then execute

**Edit:**

```
<?php

$theURL = "example.com";
$webPagesURLs = "
http://example.com
http://example1.com
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com
http://example2.com
";
foreach(explode("\n",trim($webPagesURLs)) as $webPageURL){
    $webPageContent = @file_get_contents($webPageURL);
    if(strpos($webPageContent, $theURL) !== false ){
        print "$theURL Found in <a href=$webPageURL > $webPageURL </a><br>\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdallah. As you suggested, I copied all the links to a file links.txt and created a php page with the above code and uploaded to the server. It doesn't seem to work. Instead of links.txt, can I set the URLs in an array and still use this code. Sorry,  I am very new to programming.

Comment: This is beautiful. Works perfectly. Cannot upvote it as I don't have the rep yet. But thanks a ton.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of links  that can be added to the array? Or do I need a better server to run more links?

Comment: maybe the time limit is ending, you can set the time limit to infinity by putting this set_time_limit(0); after the foreach line, though if you have a LOT of links (2000+), then i recommend working with python since its a lot faster and can deal with threads.